# Can't log in to PhpAdmin after updating Java

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I recently updated Java, and now I can't login to PhpAdmin. It gives me

> 2054 (Server sent charset unknown to the client please report to developers(mysqli_real_connect)) error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIND my.ini file and add the following code

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

some times it may occur due to connector, so make sure that your connector is working fine. Thank you